# SQL Query between dates in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, date, between

I've a problem making a sql query in VBA using excel and an access database. In mi VBA code I've two data variables with this content:

DateMin = 31/07/2014 22:00:00

DateMax = 01/08/2014 06:00:00

And I have an access database with many data with a date field. I'm trying to extract from the database, data with dates between my two variables and I'm coding this:

```
sql = "SELECT Date FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & DateMin & "# AND #" & DateMax & "#
```

But doesn't works. Results are incorrect, with dates that aren't between my two dates.

However if I change the sentence and code this

```
sql = "SELECT Date FROM Table WHERE Date > #" & DateMin & "#
```

It works! Gives data with higher dates than DateMin but I haven't DateMax to stop it. I think the problem is in the second part of my first code, because if I code

```
sql = "SELECT Date FROM Table WHERE Date < #" & DateMax & "#
```

I have no data! Why doesn't give me data lower than DateMax? Because of that I think doesn't works the BETWEEN sentence.

Sorry for my english, i'm trying to explain better I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use an **unambiguous** date format. When you have a date formated `00/00/0000`, Access has to guess whether that's `dd/mm/yyyy` (British) or `mm/dd/yyyy` (American).

Your `DateMin` (`31/07/2014 22:00:00`) can only be interpreted as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss`, (31 is an invalid month, so it must be a day) so this is the format that Access will use.

However, your `DateMax` (`01/08/2014 06:00:00`) is being interpreted in *American* format - as `8th January 2014` rather than `1st August 2014`.

The easiest way to get around this is to supply your dates in ISO format (`yyyymmdd`) or supply the month as a short word (`dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss` - eg `01 Aug 2014 06:00:00`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm trying to change date fields and date variable formats in excel and access but doesn't works yet... :(

Comment: Sorry but I can't solve this. In access, in date field, i've change format to "dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and in excel, i'm coding with date formatted in same format and no data is displayed :(

Comment: You need to change the date format in your *query* (`sql = "SELECT Date FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & DateMin & "# AND #" & DateMax & "#`) - DateMin and DateMax need to be formatted as `dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`