# SQL Filter doesn't work with past year

Tags: sql, vb.net, filtering

I got a very strange problem.

When I filter my data in the current year everything is working fine:
[image]
But If I try to go back a year, suddenly I get a blank report...
[image]

Going to the next year isn't a problem, like you can see here:
[image]

My code is:

```
These 2 values come through as a 'date' in a private sub
datumvan = DateTimePickerVan.Value.ToLocalTime
datumtot = DateTimePickerTot.Value.ToLocalTime


Dim culture As New CultureInfo("pt-BR")
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM [Geschiedenis$] WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN '" & datumvan.ToString("d", culture) & "' AND '" & datumtot.ToString("d", culture) & "'"
```

See also how the sql looks like if it goes to the debugging:
[image]

So to conclude: everything is working fine unless I go to the previous year.
If I place: NOT BETWEEN, everything is reversed, and I see all the data.

I tried to replace BETWEEN with >= and <= as well, but the same thing occurred.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you've got your date parameters in the wrong order.   The earlier date needs to be the first parameter, and the later date needs to be the second parameter.   Stop the debugger on your sql string line and look at the values of the date parameters.

Comment: Looks to me like you are storing or treating Date data as a string.  If so, you cant expect it to act like a date.

Comment: Tab Alleman: I updated my post, so you can see the sql string and that the dates are in the correct place.
Plutonix: What do I need to change then in order to place my date in the dd/mm/yyyy format as a date?

Comment: the ticks and .ToString are converting the Dates (a value type) to Text/String.  There is nothing between "3" and "0" because "3" evaluates as larger than "0" in a TEXT COMPARE.  If the dbCols are a Date type, get rid of the ticks and .ToString()

Comment: Thanks for the response, but If I remove the .tostring, then I don't get any result at all, since my selection date is in mm/dd format, and my search data in dd/mm.  That was why I needed the .ToString("d", culture)
See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: If you run the query against your database directly - with the previous year concatenated string, do you get results?

Comment: A `DateTime` type does not have a format.  They are just a value.  The format is just how it is displayed to the user (and/or you).  What is the db column type for these?  (your link is describing how to customize output, it does not change the contents/style/value of the data data - `ToString` is a *conversion*).

Comment: These are being inserted as: DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") into an excel sheet.

Comment: Using .ToString converts the DataTime value to text.  Dont do that.  Save Dates data as Dates, remove all the ticks and ToString and it will work.  For the user, set the columns to format the date in whatever fashion you want. BETWEEN wont work the same on text/string data as it will with value types (int, Date etc)

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aangemeld is obviously a date, as it should be. So you must compare Aangemeld with dates. In order to do so,

- first convert the dates to strings in VB. Make this a specific date format, rather than relying on some region settings. E.g. `datumvan.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`
- then convert the string to date in SQL. Again don't rely on database settings, but name the format you are using.

How to convert a string to a date in SQL depends on the DBMS you are using. Here are some examples:

MySQL:

```
" ... WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" & datumvan.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "','%d/%m/%Y') AND ... "
```

SQL_Server:

```
" ... WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'" & datumvan.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "',103) AND ... "
```

Oracle:

```
" ... WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & datumvan.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "','dd/mm/yyyy') AND ... "
```

Many DBMS (such as MySQL, SQL-Server, and PostgreSQL) also accept a string in ISO format as as date literal.

```
" ... WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN '" & datumvan.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "' AND ... "
```

In Oracle such a literal must be preceded by DATE:

```
" ... WHERE Aangemeld BETWEEN DATE'" & datumvan.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "' AND ... "
```

One more thing: I don't know if this is the case in other DBMS, too, but I know that Oracle treats a date without time as a date at midnight, as it only knows datetime data type. So a between clause would exclude the last day. Which is why in Oracle you would compare TRUNC(Aangemeld) instead of Aangemeld.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

I was finally able to get it to work.
Based on all your hints, and also the page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058768/sql-query-between-dates-in-vba

My main problem was the following:

ou should always use an umambiguous date format. When you have a date formated 00/00/0000, Access has to guess whether that's dd/mm/yyyy (British) or mm/dd/yyyy (American).

The easiest way to get around this is to supply your dates in ISO format (yyyymmdd) or supply the month as a short word (dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss - eg 01 Aug 2014 06:00:00)

Comment: ISO Format is good, month name abbreviation isn't, because again you would rely on regional settings (December being either 'Dec' for December or 'Dez' for Dezember or 'Dic' for Diciembre or whatever other regional name).

Comment: mmm, thats true Thorsten.
But I don't like the ISO format in my datagridview, so after my query I will format the output again to a date like mm/dd/yyyy.

Thanks again

Comment: The output? It is the WHERE clause where you compare values and need a reliable format. In your SELECT clause you can use any other format or don't format at all. Your query showed `SELECT *`. Did you change that?

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't know that I could do that.
Everything is working now with "SELECT ..., FORMAT(Aangemeld, 'dd/MM/yyyy-hh:mm:ss') FROM ...
Thanks for all the help Thorsten!